# How do I store all results from an SQL query in a multidimensional array?

Tags: php, sql

hello every one i want to convert my array into other array type , plz help me out . I
m using this

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
```

and output is

```
Array ( [user_id] => 250 [name] => a [age] => sfsf [pic_path] => )
```

but i want the the output in this format

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [user_id] => 250 [name] => a [age] => sfsf [pic_path] => ) [1] => Array ( [user_id] => 251 [name] => b [age] => sfsfs [pic_path] => ) )
```

so what function i should us to get the array in this format

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
$data = array(); // create a variable to hold the information
while (($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) !== false){
  $data[] = $row; // add the row in to the results (data) array
}

print_r($data); // print result
```

---

**Update Feb '17** Now that it's 2017, it's advised you use PDOs over mysql_*. A lot safer and can return this natively with `fetchAll` (as shown in `TrexXx's answer).

Comment: @umar: Not a problem, glad to help.

Comment: I pretend that the '!== false' is not needed. Is it a typo ?

Comment: @mat.viguier should keep it as it returns fetched results. If the array is empty, that's also falsy without being an error. But def move to PDO, this api is deprecated and removed in php 7

Comment: @BradChristie, if false, $data is returned empty. If empty, $data is returned empty. Am I falsy myslef with it ? In fact, you're true with PDO. While the OP works on mysql, I work with mssql, and PDO seems to be a pain now ...

Answer (score 6):

The only way to avoid doing a loop would to use [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (PHP Data Objects) which is a better way to access database in PHP and you could do this :

```php
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'root', '');
    
$q = $pdo->query('select * from yourtable');
$r = $q->fetchAll();
    
var_dump($r);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need to store all rows returned by the query in an array, try this:

```
$result = array(); 

while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC) ){
    $result[] = $row
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$row = array();
$row[] = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
```

Normally you'd assign the results like this in a loop

```
$rows = array();
while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {       
    $rows[] = $result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't get a multi-dimensional array from the resultset of your SQL query in just one command. You need to repeat the function `mysql_fetch_array` once per SQL result row.

Also you can use `mysql_fetch_assoc` to get the results as an associative array.

To achieve your goal:

```
$num = mysql_num_rows($result);
for ($i = 0; $i < $num; $i++)
{
    $myArray[] = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
}
```