# PHP store sql query in array, access each column using the array index

Tags: php

I have seen this question/answers [How do I store all results from an SQL query in a multidimensional array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5353905/how-do-i-store-all-results-from-an-sql-query-in-a-multidimensional-array)
But its not exatcly what I am looking for, in this answer, the array index is the row, so array[0] will contain first row.

What I want is array[0] to contain the first column. array[1] contains the second column. There will be only one row to be returned from the sql query.

How can I do this?

(havent test the code im on my phone)

would this work?

```
$data = array(); // create a variable to hold the information
while (($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) !== false){
  $data[] = $row; // add the row in to the results (data) array
  $newArray = explode(",", $data[0]);
  echo $newArray[0]//return first column?
}
```

Comment: _“What I want is array[0] to contain the first column. array[1] contains the second column.”_ - well then use `$data = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM);`, and done … _“There will be only one row to be returned from the sql query.”_ - then there is no need for a loop to begin with.

Comment: @CBroe yeah the loop is unnecessary, i just copy the answer from the link provided and changed it a bit so i could ask a relevant question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM)) {
    $count = count($row);
    for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
        $data[$i][] = $row[$i];
    }
}
```

Tested output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
            [3] => 4
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => column 1.2
            [1] => column 2.2
            [2] => column 3.2
            [3] => column 4.2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => column 1.3
            [1] => column 2.3
            [2] => column 3.3
            [3] => column 4.3
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => column 1.4
            [1] => column 2.4
            [2] => column 3.4
            [3] => column 4.4
        )

)
```